# Local file reader for cordova windows project

Tags: windows, cordova, plugins, local, filereader

Is it possible to read files (pdf,...) from my cordova windows app folder ?

I already use FileOpener to read local files in Android Tablets but this plugin is developed for Android use.

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [cordova-plugin-file-opener2](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2). It supports for windows phone too.

Add this from Command line:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2`

Then use this JS lines for opening a pdf file with default app

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    '/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'application/pdf', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```

This plug in is working fine in windows phone 8.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, i'm not developping a cordova windows Phone app but a windows8.1 one.

Comment: Which path do you use for Windows applications? E.g. i have "www/documents/test.pdf". Which path i use instead of "/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf' ?